# How to change color from red to green if mobile verification status changes?

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, twilio

I am currently working on a project (based on Django), which has a user profile where users can verify their mobile number. I am using Twilio for that.

What I want is when a user views their profile, there should be a option to "Verify your mobile number" directly below the mobile number field, which will be in red. As soon as the user verifies this (via some backend Django/python stuff) and returns to the profile page again, that message should be "verified" (in green).

I want CSS and JavaScript code to achieve that because for SMS verification and all the backend stuff i already have the code.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by AJAX, here are the steps

1. create a new view that checks the user status e.g is_verified_user and return True/False
2. write a JS function that will call the view and check response, it shall be something like this

   ```
    function check_user_status(){
            $.ajax({"url":"{%url 'is_verified_user'%}", success:function(data){
            if (data == "True")
                 {     //change the colors}
            else
                  setTimeout("check_user_status",3000)
                // Check again in 3 seconds
           }
           })
        }
   ```
3. Once the user clicks on 'verify your mobile number', call the `check_user_status` function to start checking.

P.S you need JQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the api response and use the ternary operator

Example in React JS

const [state, setState] = useState(false)

useEffect( () => {
// call api

let response = axios.get('/')

let result = response.verified ? true :  false

setState(result)

},[state])

return (

)